# how to authenticate against on premises crm 2016

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, microsoft-dynamics, adal, dynamics-crm-2016

We are running CRM 2016, and I am currently attempting to authenticate using the [code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg327838.aspx) provided by msdn:

```
    // TODO Substitute your correct CRM root service address, 
string resource = "https://mydomain.crm.dynamics.com";

// TODO Substitute your app registration values that can be obtained after you
// register the app in Active Directory on the Microsoft Azure portal.
string clientId = "e5cf0024-a66a-4f16-85ce-99ba97a24bb2";
string redirectUrl = "http://localhost/SdkSample";


// Authenticate the registered application with Azure Active Directory.
AuthenticationContext authContext = 
    new AuthenticationContext("https://login.windows.net/common", false);
AuthenticationResult result = authContext.AcquireToken(resource, clientId, new
                                                       Uri(redirectUrl));
```

**What exactly does the redirectUrl mean in the following context?**

```
string redirectUrl = "http://localhost/SdkSample";
```

**How do I identify where the AuthenticationContext is for our environment, as in this line:**

```
AuthenticationContext authContext = 
new AuthenticationContext("https://login.windows.net/common", false);
```

Comment: From docs `redirectUri = Address to return to upon receiving a response from the authority.` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn528721.aspx

Comment: Same doc has [Discover the authority at run time](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg327838.aspx#Anchor_3) but I am guessing that is for Dynamics 365 and not on premise

Comment: this looks promising https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334502.aspx#Anchor_3

Comment: Quoting documentation `For an on-premises or an Internet-facing deployment (IFD) installation of Microsoft Dynamics 365, the client proxy classes use claims-based authentication if an STS server is available. Otherwise, Active Directory authentication is used.`

Comment: @Nkosi i really appreciate the help, but practically speaking i am lost. i am able to authenticate without issue against HTTP endpoint; however, when i issue a request against HTTPS, i get a 401 -- BUT when i try to do this directly through the browser it works fine, also postman works, but doing it through VS does not work --

Comment: i'm specifically trying this - it works with http, but not https: private HttpClient getNewHttpClient(string userName,string password,string domainName, string webAPIBaseAddress)
{
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler() { Credentials = new NetworkCredential(userName, password, domainName) });
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(webAPIBaseAddress);
    client.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 2, 0);
    return client;
} https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt595798.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: For http client to work with https you need to do this before creating the client `//Handle TLS protocols
            System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol =
                System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls
                | System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls11
                | System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;`